# How to search multiple files in folder for a string with a minimum number of characters?

Tags: powershell

On Windows in Powershell, how would I search multiple files in a folder for lines with a minimum of 16 characters? Further, is there a way to specify that the string should only be numerical?

I have been looking at `Select-String`, but I don't see an option for min characters.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: `gci -Path .\ -File -Recurse | ? { $_.BaseName -match "^\d+$" -and $_.BaseName.Length -ge 16 }`. Take a look into `Get-ChildItem`, `Where-Object` (*or any filtering options*), and *Regex*.

Comment: Very nice @AbrahamZinala.  You could also adjust the regex to '^\d{16,}$' and remove the 2nd part.

Comment: Should the name match these criterias or should this be the content of the files?

Comment: @Daniel, for whatever reason I thought that was gonne cause an issue, but that's definitely the way I would go as well. Thank ya(:

Comment: OK ... but Why '^' and why '$'  ... the OP didn't mention it has to be at the beginning or at the end ...

Comment: @Olaf, "*Further is there a way to specify that the string should only be numerical?*". Based it off that.

Comment: I'd try it with this: `Select-String -Path * -Pattern '\d{16,}'`

Comment: I'd pipe that after a `gci -r` (*if recurse is needed*), but that may also be a better way to go about it.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala That does not translate it for me that the string has to be at the beginning or at the end. Let's wait for a reply.  ;-)

Comment: I am going to test this out now and let you know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: @Alexnl You actually may specify a little more detailed what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Yes. More detail would be good.  Are you looking for filenames that have 16+ digits or lines inside the files that are 16+ digits?

Comment: I am looking for lines inside files that are 16+ characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using the current directory (`.`) and a pattern matching all `.txt` files as an example:

To output all lines in matching files with at least 16 characters:

```sh
Get-Content .\*.txt | Where-Object Length -ge 16
```

To additionally ensure that all such lines are composed of decimal digits<sup>[1]</sup> only:

```sh
Get-Content .\*.txt | Where-Object { $_.Length -ge 16 -and $_ -match '^\d+$' }
```

Note:

- Each output line is decorated with metadata by [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), notably: property `.PSPath` contains the line's originating file path, and `.ReadCount` contains the `1`-based line number inside the file of origin.

The following command uses output formatting via [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) to make these properties visible:

```sh
Get-Content .\*.txt | Where-Object { $_.Length -ge 16 -and $_ -match '^\d+$' } | 
  Format-Table -Force @{ Name='Line'; Expression={ $_ } }, PSPath, ReadCount
```

- `-Force` is required to override the default output formatting for `[string]` instances (which is to print just the string itself)
- The [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) is used to define a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) that outputs the line itself, i.e. the string's content; note that you could use the same technique to *rename* properties, such as renaming `PSPath` to `FilePath`, and `ReadCount` to `LineNumber`.

Sample output:

```sh
Line              PSPath                            ReadCount
----              ------                            ---------
1111111111111111  C:\Users\jdoe\foo.txt                    10
22222222222222222 C:\Users\jdoe\bar.txt                    12
```

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, `\d` matches all Unicode characters considered digits, which includes digits from different writing systems; you can use `[0-9]` to limit matching to the ASCII-range digits.</sup>